# Unexpected token: operator (>) | update or replace uglify-js to handle ES6?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, aframe, uglifyjs

This is my first time building an a-frame app with react and when running `npm run-script build` in my cmd prompt I come across this error.

```
Failed to compile.

static/js/main.9516bce8.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: operator (>) [./~/aframe/dist/aframe-master.js:57303,0][static/js/main.9516bce8.js:80512,32]
```

`"aframe": "^1.0.4"`

```
"webpack": {
  "version": "2.6.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/-/webpack-2.6.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-LgRX8KuxrF3zqxBsacZy8jZ4Xwc=",
  "requires": {
    "acorn": "^5.0.0",
    "acorn-dynamic-import": "^2.0.0",
    "ajv": "^4.7.0",
    "ajv-keywords": "^1.1.1",
    "async": "^2.1.2",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.0.0",
    "interpret": "^1.0.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "json5": "^0.5.1",
    "loader-runner": "^2.3.0",
    "loader-utils": "^0.2.16",
    "memory-fs": "~0.4.1",
    "mkdirp": "~0.5.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "source-map": "^0.5.3",
    "supports-color": "^3.1.0",
    "tapable": "~0.2.5",
    "uglify-js": "^2.8.27",
    "watchpack": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack-sources": "^0.2.3",
    "yargs": "^6.0.0"
  },
```

based on my research i'm guessing the version of uglify that i'm using doesn't support ES6
but I can't find anything online that can help me update or replace uglify-js to handle ES6

Answer (score 0):

You can update it with

`npm update uglify-js`

which updates the package to the latest version that satisfies it version tag.

If this new version does not work, you can update it to a specific version

`npm update uglify-js@3.0.5`

or just update it to the latest one

`npm update uglify-js@latest`

Be careful because updates might break some existing code

Comment: This change did nothing, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[terser-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser-webpack-plugin) works for me using webpack v4. it does support ES6+

Comment: Hey, so I tried installing terser-webpack-plugin but i'm still getting the same uglify error?

I did the following steps - (1) npm uninstall webpack (2) Deleted the node-modules folder and the package-lock.json file from your project's folder. (3)  npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev (4) npm install (5) npm install webpack@3.11.0 (6) npm uninstall uglify-js.

Comment: not sure if it is something do with webpack version, i am using webpack v4 and it works. hope some more experienced people will help, good luck